# Fetch employee list along with number of task completed by each employee, in Laravel MongoDB

Tags: laravel, mongodb, jenssegers-mongodb, laravel-mongodb

I am using [Laravel MongoDB library](https://github.com/mongodb/laravel-mongodb) (formerly know as [Laravel Jenssegers MongoDB library](https://github.com/mongodb/laravel-mongodb/tree/3.9#laravel-version-compatibility)).

This is my employees collection

```
{
    _id         : {$oid: 2ndkj3720eA83b24},
    name        : 'Employee1',
    status      : 'a',
    deleted_at  : null
}
```

This is my task collection:-

```
{
    _id              : {$oid: 893jfo2ok01398190},
    name             : 'Task 1',
    employees        : [
                         {$oid: ae2nvg6788eA83b24},
                         {$oid: be09gh56701398190},
                         {$oid: bf0e28bfi45202bc0}
                       ],
    complete_status  : 'c',
    status           : 'a',
    deleted_at       : null
}
```

The employees column in task collection is an array of object ids of employees.

This is how I fetch employee list:-

```
$employeeQuery  = Employee::where(array(
                                'status'          => Globals::SMALL_CHAR_ACTIVE,
                                'deleted_at'      => NULL
                            ));

if($employeeQuery->count() > 0) {
    $employeeListing = $employeeQuery->get()->toArray();
}
```

But now I have to fetch employee list along with number of completed tasks for each employee. Like this:-

```
{
    _id  : {$oid: 2ndkj3720eA83b24},
    name : 'Employee1',
    task_completed: 23
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Where is the relationship? I mean, how do you connect the task with the employee? And a quick tip, you do not need to do `count() > 0`, because you are literally counting each row that matches your filters, what you want to do is use `exists()`, so when database find a single row, it is enough and it returns, so  you do not need to count all of them (this is very performant when you have a lot of rows). You can also directly do `$employeeCollection = Employee::where(...)->get()`, then `if ($employeeCollection->isNotEmpty()) { $employeeListing = $employeeCollection->toArray(); }`

Comment: Sorry, I read it again and you shared the relationship (DB), did you set up the relationship on the code? Is the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships) not understandable? how can we help you set it up?